# Are tag-wikis always presented with the tag-excerpt in front?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-wiki, tag-excerpt

Many tag-wikis start with the same or similar phrase as the tag-excerpt which looks somewhat odd and redundant, since the tag-excerpt is always included when displaying the tag-wiki. ((I vaguely believe that it was not included previously.))

So are tag wikis always presented that way? Which would permit to remove the redundant introductory sentence in the tag-wiki text.

As an example, consider [the c wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) which includes this somewhat unnecessary repetition (not that I intend to edit it...).

Comment: While the tag excerpt is never (that I know of) without the tag, it's only shown together with the tag-wiki if someone explicitly asks for it.

Comment: @Deduplicator: There must be some misunderstanding: The tax excerpt is shown alone, when hovering over it. And when looking at a tag (see link above), the excerpt is always included in the beginning.

Comment: Hm. Seems they changed it when you are looking at the tag-wiki in the new nav or generally for the better. But what do you mean, the tag-excerpt is shown but the tag isn't there to be seen? Aren't you hovering over it, and the details (including excerpt) are shown below?